# Outputting all items in wincombobox to local datatable in UFT

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

Hi I am trying to output the all items in a wincombobox to the local datatable in UFT but it only outputs the last item. I have outputted to a msgbox and each selection appears but not in the datatable. Any guidance?

```
Dim count,i,item,label

count = Window("Maestro Crew").Dialog("Update Application Security").WinComboBox("Work Group").GetItemsCount
For i = 0 to count-1 
  item = Window("Maestro Crew").Dialog("Update Application Security").WinComboBox("Work Group").Select (i)
  Window("Maestro Crew").Dialog("Update Application Security").WinComboBox("Work Group").Output CheckPoint("Work Group_3")
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it is outputting each of them but to that particular cell. And you can only see the last output in the datable after executing the script. Try to run your code in debug mode put breakpoints on the line which is having output checkpoint and check the modifications in the datatable during debugging.